Detect state changes during a long-running Promise
How do I detect if a state change occurred during a long-running API call to some external server?
My application takes some input from the user and sends it to a server for calculating the results. This calculation can take a long time, and during that time the user might grow impatient and change the input and press enter again. (The input affects computation time, and a smaller input finishes faster). I'm currently using Promises to make the API call and render the results on callback.
How can I detect if the input changed during the Promise, and scrap the result if it did? (With the assumption that a new Promise the user triggered will have the results they want)
Here is a small sample code of my application:
import React, { useState } from "react";

const StateChangeTest = () => {
  const [inputNumber, setInputNumber] = useState();

  const computeResults = async () => {
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000)); // mock some long-running API call

    // QUESTION: How do I check here if the inputNumber state has changed during the Promise()?
    // If the state has changed at all then scrap the result / break / return
    const result = inputNumber * 100;

    // Don't do this if inputNumber changed
    displayResults(result);
  };

  const displayResults = (result) => {
    console.log("The result is " + result);
    alert("The result is " + result);
  };

  const handleSearchInputChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setInputNumber(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter" || e.keyCode === 10 || e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent newline from being inserted into input
      computeResults(inputNumber);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="number"
        onChange={handleSearchInputChange}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        placeholder="Enter a number"
        value={inputNumber}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default StateChangeTest;

Steps to reproduce:

Enter a number (i.e. 5), and press enter.
Before the Promise finishes, change the number (i.e. 10) and press enter again.
Two results will be displayed to the user, how can I abort the first one?


See also this answer. In react, you'd store the abort controller in a ref (per component) not in a global variable.
